# css position: relative; stick to bottom

Tags: html, css, position

```
<body style="min-height:2000px;">
    <div id="test" style="position:relative;bottom:0;">
         some dynamically changed content
    </div>
</body>
```

**What do i expect:**
-If `#test` height is greater or equal to body's it should stick to bottom (as it happens now cuz of block model)
-If `#test` height is less than body's it should however stick to bottom, having white space above it. (which doesn't happen, `#test` doesn't stick to bottom).

-Using **position:absolute is not acceptable** as then `#test` will not influence body height when `#test` is higher than body.
-Using **position:fixed is not acceptable** as then `#test` will stick to bottom of window, not body.

Q: Can I get what I expect **using css only**? How?

Sorry for poor English, however I think the question is easy to understand.
Thank you.

P.S.: I need that in css because some dynamically changed content is changed via js and I want to avoid recalculating `#test` div position each time it changes.

**UPD:**

I've also tried some `display:inline-block; vertical-align:bottom;` stuff still no result.

**UPD2:**

Thank you guys, still it seems, that easiest way is just to add a couple of lines to my javascript to recalculate body height on `#test` height change.

Comment: I guess you are looking for sticky footer..

Comment: If you are really looking for sticky footer try this - http://mystrd.at/modern-clean-css-sticky-footer/ .Best solution so far

Comment: I haven't met any "sticky footer" solutions without position:fixed or postition:absolute. I'm wondering, if there is any.

Comment: Please, reread question. There i told why 'absolute' is not acceptable. Plus content is changed dynamically, so i can't tell exact height of #test without js calculations.

Comment: Why do you have the `min-height: 2000px;`? Is this higher than your screensize?

Comment: Just Try the [Ryan Fait Sticky Footer](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/) , Here is a **[Demo](http://codepen.io/hashem/pen/eBLKD)**.

Comment: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples/sticky-footer.html

Comment: @sander use `position: absolute or fixed` to `#test` and give `position: relative` to `body` tag. that will fix for sure.

Comment: @rednaw : yes, but this doesn't matter.

Comment: @Mr_Green not helped :(

Comment: @ others: #test height is changed dynamically by js SO i can't use standart sticky footer things as they assume that i already know the height of the footer.

Answer (score 30):

I know it's an old question, but you could try doing:

```
top: 100%;
transform: translateY(-100%);
```

Transform operates with the size of the element itself, therefore it will climb back to the container at the very bottom. You can use letters for all 3 axis.

Answer (score 8):

Because of the dynamic height nature of #test you cannot do this with CSS alone. However, if you're already using jQuery, a quick .height() call should be able to get you what you need (#test height needs to be subtracted from positioning it 2000px from the top).

```
<style>
body {
    min-height: 2000px;
}

#test {
    position: relative;
    top: 2000px;
} 
</style>

<script>
var testHeight = $("#test").height();
$( "#test" ).css({
    margin-top: -testHeight;
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

The only two pure-CSS ways to create sticky footer of dynamic height I know are using flexboxes (no support in IE9-, unfortunately) and using [CSS tables](http://jsfiddle.net/sB85F/):

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;    
    margin: 0;
}
body {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    min-height:2000px;
}
#test {
    display: table-footer-group;
    height: 1px; /* just to prevent proportional distribution of the height */
}
```

Comment: `display: table-footer-group;` works like a charm. Especially when the body element has a dynamic height and `min-height: 100vh;`.

Answer (score 4):

It is very much possible using `relative` position. this is how you do it.

Assume height of your footer is going to be 40px. Your container is `relative` and footer is also `relative`. All you have to do is add  `bottom: -webkit-calc(-100% + 40px);`. your footer will always be at the bottom of your container.

**HTML will be like this**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS will be like this**

```
.container{
  height:400px;
  width:600px;
  border:1px solid red;
  margin-top:50px;
  margin-left:50px;
  display:block;
}
.footer{
  width:100%;
  height:40px;
  position:relative;
   float:left;
  border:1px solid blue;
  bottom: -webkit-calc(-100% + 40px);
   bottom:calc(-100% + 40px);
}
```

[Live example here](http://cssdeck.com/labs/i6jrmpv2)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
#footer{
    position:fixed;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    height:30px;
    width:100%;
    background:#999;
}
/* IE6 */
* html #footer{
    position:absolute;
    top:expression((0-(footer.offsetHeight)+(document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : document.body.clientHeight)+(ignoreMe = document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop))+'px');
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/As3bP/ - position: fixed; is the obvious way of doing this, and if this affects your layout, try posting your problems here. It'd be easier to modify the CSS of your content than trying to find another way of doing this.

The IE6 expression is not good for speed at all but it works, read about that here: http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/high-performance-sites-rule-7-avoid-css-expressions-7202.html

**EDIT** Read your edits, please forget the above. To be stuck at the bottom of the body, it'd be easy to position it in your HTML. This is simple stuff, please post example code if you need further help. Positioning something at the bottom of the page, by default, positions at the bottom of the page.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TAQ4d/ if you really actually need that.

Comment: I'll try to explain:1) take code from my question.2) Change position:relative to position:absolute. #test sticks to bottom of the body, that's good. 3) Add "height:3000px" to #test's style. It is still at the bottom of the body (good), but the body is still 2000px and 1000px of #test is hidden above the body (that's bad);

Answer (score 1):

short answer: No YOU can't do this with pure css because it is just the reversed direction to the normal flow of page (I mean bottom to top);
you can use this plugin which is very easy to use [stickyjs](http://stickyjs.com/);
use it with `bottomSpacing: 0`

**EDIT**
this plugin uses `position: fixed` too!
then I think you should write it down by yourself or have someone to write it for you :D

Comment: I was afraid of that. Now i'll need to add more calculations to my js.

Comment: and as far as i know there is not something like that

Comment: @sander it is possible using html5 and css3. check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

if u dont want to use `position:absolute; left:0; bottom:0;` then u may try simple `margin-top:300px;`...

Comment: That's what im going to do now. As long as #test height changes dynamically i will need to do that with JS.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes it is Posiible with CSS only:**

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="test">
        some dynamically
        changed content
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    line-height: 2000px;
}

#test{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    line-height: initial;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/otxz4q5y/1/)

If you want to have the text on the bottom of the screen then you can use:

```
body {
    line-height: 100vh;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here are solution I come up with

```
<ul class="navbar">

    <li><a href="/themes-one/Welcome"> Welcome <i></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="/themes-one/Portfolio"> Portfolio <i></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="/themes-one/Services"> Services <i></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="/themes-one/Blogs"> Blogs <i></i></a><i class="arrow right"></i>
        <ul class="subMenu">
            <li><a href="/themes-one/Why-Did-Mint-Net-CMS-Born"> Why Did Mint Net CMS Born <i></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="/themes-one/Apply-AJAX-and-Mansory-in-gallery"> Apply AJAX and Mansory in gallery <i></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="/themes-one/Why-did-Minh-Vo-create-Mint-Net-CMS"> Why did Minh Vo create Mint Net CMS <i></i></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/themes-one/About"> About <i></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="/themes-one/Contact"> Contact <i></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="/themes-one/Estimate"> Estimate <i></i></a></li>


</ul>

<style>

    .navbar {
        display: block;
        background-color: red;
        height: 100px;
    }

    li {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: bottom;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: antiquewhite;
        line-height: 100px;
    }

    li > a {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: bottom;
        line-height:initial;
    }

    li >ul {
        display: none;
    }


</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am late too, but I think `margin-top: auto` will do the trick:

```
#test {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

We do like that:

Html:

```
<body>
   <div id="bodyDiv">
      <!-- web site content is here -->
   </div>
</body>
<footer>
   <!-- Footer content is here -->
</footer>
```

Jquery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() 
{
   $('#bodyDiv').css("min-height",screen.height);
});`
```

dynamically change content element min-height attribute according to screen resolution.

Answer (score -1):

Old post, I know, but yet another solution would be to create a wrapper for your content with a minimal height of 100vh - footerHeight
this solution requires that you know the height of the footer...

```
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    your content
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    footer content
  </div>
</body>
```

and your css would look like this:

```
.wrapper {
  min-height: calc( 100vh - 2em );
}
.footer {
  height: 2em;
}
```